# Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null thrown when testing component

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

So I am trying to test this component and its a simple component that gets a value from an observable and displays it to the screen. For some reason when I try and test it, it throws an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null thrown` error.

I am initializing the `userProfile` variable so it should be there, unless I am misunderstanding the error. What can I do to get this to pass?

Here is the component file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/auth/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'user-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './user-dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-dropdown.component.scss']
})
export class UserDropdownComponent implements OnInit {

  ENV = environment;
  userProfile: Object = {};

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getUserProfile().subscribe(response => {
      this.userProfile = response.profile;
    }, err => { console.log(err); });
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.authService.logout();
  }
}
```

here is the spec file:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { UserDropdownComponent } from './user-dropdown.component';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FilterPipe } from '../../filters/filter.pipe';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/auth/auth.service';
import { HttpClient, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

describe('UserDropdownComponent', () => {
  let component: UserDropdownComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserDropdownComponent>;
  let authServiceStub: any;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    authServiceStub = {
      getUserProfile: () => of({ profile: {} })
    };

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        UserDropdownComponent,
        FilterPipe
      ],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
      imports: [
        NgbModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: AuthService,
          useValue: authServiceStub
        },
        HttpClient,
        HttpHandler,
        CookieService,
        {
          provide: Router,
          useClass: class { navigate = jasmine.createSpy('navigate'); }
        }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserDropdownComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

and here is the HTML where it is referencing the `userProfile.name`:

```
<li *ngIf="userProfile" class="nav-item" ngbDropdown #userDropdown="ngbDropdown" display="dynamic" placement="bottom-right">
  <a class="nav-link" role="button" id="userDropdown" ngbDropdownToggle>
    <i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>
    {{ userProfile.name }}
    <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="userDropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item">Profile</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item">My Downloads</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="logout()">Logout</a>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the correct behavior. You have the property "userProfile" initialized to empty object, hence, in ngIf, it will result in true as empty object is a truthy value. You should initialize it as an undefined or null if you don't want the html block to render unless there's userProfile is defined.

Comment: If I remove the initialization and just make it a declaration I still get the test fail :(

Comment: Yes same error message. I mean if I run the app normally it runs just fine

Comment: Makes sense, {}.name should not throw "cannot read name of null", as it's an empty object not null. I'll look at it again